# How do I change the URL based on an AJAX request without changing/refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, url-rewriting

I'm working on a site where users can click on certain elements that trigger an AJAX request that inject information onto the page. For SEO reasons, I want this to rewrite the URL but for usability reasons I don't want to refresh the page. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to change the page (browser) url or some link's url and not have to refresh the page? Of course, changing the link's url is easy and you don't have to refresh the page for that. So if you want to change the page url and not have to refresh the page, then the only way you could do that is to change the `hash` part of the url. Although if you have some function listening for a hash change then that function is going to be triggered. Any other change to the browser url **will** trigger a page reload or redirect to that page.

Comment: I want to change the URL of the page.

Comment: If I change the hash part of the URL, will it help our SEO, or will it just change the URL in their browser locally?

Comment: If you want to rewrite urls for SEO purposes, that should be done through your .htaccess file found in the root of your site's files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `use history` api in `html5`: `pop` and `push` `state`

http://html5doctor.com/history-api/

Comment: Will this actually help the SEO, or will it just rewrite the URL in their local browser?